# Visual Studio Lightswitch and spatial data

Tags: open-source-gis, sql-server, extensions, visual-studio

I'm looking for a way to handle spatial data (for instance geography data type in SQL Server 2008) in [Visual Studio Lightswitch 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/lightswitch).

Preferably with an extension that can show data on a map. So far the only extension I have found is the one from [NetAdvantage](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/lightswitch.aspx#Overview).

Is there alternatives to this extension? Are there (open source) projects addressing this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is an free tool that connects Bing Maps and Sql Server spatial.

http://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/

Keith

Comment: Very nice find, hadn't come across it yet!